# How do re-parse a variable string that contains a variable name?

Tags: php

```
$a = 'i am a $b'; // declared before $b is declared

function x(....) {
    global $a;
    $b = 'boy';
    $c = '{$a}'; // i know this doesn't work. how can I make it work?
}
```

I want $c to return "i am a boy"

This is a simple example of my issue. In the real case, there are many variables involved. Is there a simple fix?

Comment: eval is evil but sometimes it's what you need... https://3v4l.org/kfdrF

Answer (score 0):

This is where functions come in handy. They take in the parameters and return some compiled value.

```
// create named function
function namedFn($b) {
    return "i am a $b";
}
//  or anonymous
$f = function ($b) {return "i am a $b"; };

// call function and pass $b as argument
$b = 'boy';
echo namedFn($b);
echo $f($b);
```

If you really need to reparse some string with the contents of your variables, just use `str_ireplace`

```
$a = 'i am a $b';
echo str_ireplace('$b', $b, $a); // $search , $replace , $subject
```